# Differentiation calculation

Tags: derivatives

If $a, b, p$ and $q$ are positive with $a<b$ find the x-coordinate of the stationary point of the curve $y=(x-a)^p(x-b)^q$ in the domain $a<x<b$.

This question is from the chain rule chapter, so it doesn't involve the product or quotient rule. How do I do this question?

Comment: With the chain and product rules.

Comment: you should probably use the chain rule. Use it to calculate the derivatives of $(x-a)^p$ and $(x-b)^q$ and then use the product rule to calculate the derivate of $(x-a)^p\cdot (x-b)^q$ using the derivates of both factors.

Comment: Does the chain rule chapter by any chance come after the product rule chapter...?

Comment: Nope, it comes before, which is why I am convinced there is a way to do it with the chain rule.

Comment: @Zook any advances?

Comment: I don't see any way to do it without the product rule unless you know the values of $p$ and $q$, in which case you can expand the polynomials. Or if $p=q$, in which case you can write it as $y=[(x-a)(x-b)]^p$ and expand the inner quadratic.

Comment: Textbooks have been known to make mistakes...

Comment: The answer, using the product rule, is actually pretty cool, it's a weighted average of $a$ and $b$ depending on the values of the exponents.

Comment: You could do some really really nasty expansion and factoring with the binomial theorem... I could reverse engineer it by getting there ahead of time with the product rule if you want...